# Can't reset Reactive with value is array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, reactive

- I got a problem, when i create an array
  [initial Reactive()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1G7z.png)
- And I want it reset whenever Type change.
  [reset function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv7Ky.png)
- But not working.
- Anyone has solution, please let me know, and can u please explain about why Object.assign can't work with array in Reactive(). Thanks!

Comment: We dont know what you want and whats your errors as you did not show the whole code

Comment: For variables that need to be reassigned, you should use ref()
Now you just need to call `variableName.value = newValue` to be able to assign a new value and keep it reactive. [More information](https://github.com/vuejs/docs/issues/801#issuecomment-757587022)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors  and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown what's the meaning of " not working", t]he question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reset your reactive data you can just do it like this. I have written different approach.

1. This if your only using the index 0, you can just reset the index zero like this.

```js
watch(() => record.value.type, () => {

  state[0] = {value: '', weight: ''};
})
```

2. If you want to reset every item inside you state:

```js
watch(() => record.value.type, () => {
  state.forEach((item, index) => {
    state[index] = {value: '', weight: ''};
  })
})
```

3. If you want to reset everything, and start from the very start:

```js
watch(() => record.value.type, () => {
  state.length = 0; // empty the array
  state[0] = {value: '', weight: ''} // add initial value
})
```